# Is there any way to access Protocol Buffers with python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

We use Python 3.x in our projects. But the official client of Protocol Buffers only supports python 2.x.

I don't want to downgrade to python 2.x.

Comment: Protocol buffers supports Python 3 from version 2.6.0. http://protobuf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CHANGES.txt

Comment: The Google Code repository is gone, but the document that imxylz is referring to is [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/v2.6.0/CHANGES.txt).It doesn't say *how* to use Python 3 with this version, it just says that support was added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**: Python 3.x is natively supported as of version 3.0.0.

You can see versions released on GitHub here:
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

<s>**UPDATE**: The stable version of protobuf, 2.6.1, does not support Python 3.x. However, the newer 3.0.0 release (still in beta) supports Python 3.x. You can see versions released on PyPi here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf</s>

<s>No, there isn't. There is a [discussion on the protobuf google group](http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf/browse_thread/thread/b1bda93a6d1263ac?pli=1) about Python 3.X support. It indicates that Google wants to keep support for Python 2.4, so porting to Python 3.X is not easy. If the project branches or can drop support for Python 2.4 and 2.5, it would be a lot easier to port.</s>

Comment: How about proposing an edit, providing me a link, or answering the question yourself? Commenting and just telling me to google isn't very helpful.

Comment: i think @piotr meant: "Old answer[.] [P]lease[,] [G]oogle [(the company),] there are ports to python3 now [so it should have official support]"

Answer (score 7):

Here is the newer fork of most recent version of protobuf (2.5.0 + arm64 patches) at the moment that supports Python 3 and still backward compatible with Python 2.4: https://github.com/GreatFruitOmsk/protobuf-py3

Comment: How to use protoc from this package? I'm able to make protobuf working but have to manually modify generated files. How can I make protoc do the job right?

Comment: You should be able to do it as usual. Could you create an issue on github with detailed description?

Comment: I figured it out. I though that legacy protoc would be compatible with this package but I had to recompile whole protobuf-py3 and make install in system dir to replace protoc. After this it works correct.

Comment: @omikron I suggest to given 2.6 a shot. It should support python 3 out of the box.

Comment: I tried protobuf 2.6 and 2.6.1 and it's not Python 3 ready because it raises SyntaxError in protobuf/internal.

Answer (score 6):

The latest version of Google Protocol Buffers (2.6) added Python 3 support. I suggest using that.

EDIT: Nevermind. They lied in their release notes.

Answer (score 3):

There is a compatible implantation for python 3.x. https://github.com/openx/python3-protobuf

Comment: Unfortunately this fork is outdated

Comment: Discussion about Python3 protobuf on google groups : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/Qalty-PenDA

Answer (score 1):

This package should be the alpha version of Python 3 Protocol Buffer by Google.

https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0-alpha-3/protobuf-python-3.0.0-alpha-3.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Google's official library has supported Python 3 since version 3.0 (Jul 29, 2016).