# Python relative import syntax: `from . import abc.xyz`

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

**Issue:** I am trying to install [a Python3 port of Google Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/openx/python3-protobuf). When I do a `python3 setup.py test` I get the following error:

```
    File "/[*snip*]/python3-protobuf-master/python/google/protobuf/unittest_custom_options_pb2.py", line 13
    from . import google.protobuf.descriptor_pb2
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I then tried similar syntax in both my Python3 and Python2 interpreters and got the same error:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jul 23 2012, 16:48:24)
[GCC 4.5.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from . import x.y
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from . import x.y
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Question:** When is `from . import abc.xyz` valid Python syntax, if at all? I am interested in knowing if this code I downloaded is inherently malformed.

**Misc:** I chose this Python3 port of GPB from an answer on [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663468/is-there-any-way-to-access-protocol-buffers-with-python-3-x) It  is not up-to-date with regard to GPB, but I expected it to still function. Let me know if you know better about Python3 ports of GPB.

Comment: Where did that `unittest_custom_options_pb2.py` file come from? IT is not present in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/openx/python3-protobuf/tree/master/python/google/protobuf) you link to.

Comment: Ah, it appears to be autogenerated from [this file](https://github.com/openx/python3-protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/unittest_custom_options.proto) perhaps.

Comment: yes, line 1 of each of the two offending files says `# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!` But I edited them anyway as per your suggestion and the `setup.py test` ran correctly.

Comment: Looks like you found a bug in the way imports are translated to Python then.

Comment: I've left a reference to your question on the [relevant commit](https://github.com/openx/python3-protobuf/commit/cbabb9385f4cc8268e186a7889b7db6d5de14237#commitcomment-5143502).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only name a top-level object or nested module after `import`. Move the `x` name to the `from` clause:

```
from .x import y
```

or for your original problem:

```
from .google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
```

It appears the [.proto file in question](https://github.com/openx/python3-protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/unittest_custom_options.proto) is not being compiled to Python correctly. A quick scan shows that [this to be the case](https://github.com/openx/python3-protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/compiler/python/python_generator.cc#L275):

```
void Generator::PrintImports() const {
  for (int i = 0; i < file_->dependency_count(); ++i) {
    string module_name = ModuleName(file_->dependency(i)->name());
    printer_->Print("try:\n");
    printer_->Print("  from . import $module$\n", "module", module_name);
    printer_->Print("except ImportError:\n");
    printer_->Print("  import $module$\n", "module", module_name);
  }
  printer_->Print("\n");
}
```

You'll need to file a bug report with the project.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed: pull request: https://github.com/openx/python3-protobuf/pull/7